# How do I get my program to prompt for user input and store it into an array using a function?

Tags: c

I need to use a function to take user input, store it into an array to be passed to another function to either decrypt or encrypt the message.

```
  int main()
{
    char inputBuf[SIZE];

    do
    {
        switch (getUserChoice())
        {
            case 1:
            getShift();
            break;

            case 2:
            getString(inputBuf[SIZE]);
            break;

        }
    } while(getUserChoice() != 4);

    return 0;
}

void getString(char inputBuf[SIZE])
{
    char inputBuf[SIZE];
    printf("Input: \n");
    fgets(inputBuf, SIZE, stdin)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements to your code...

Arrays get passed as pointers.  So declare the function consuming your array as a function taking a pointer and a max length for the array.

You still need to supply definitions for `getShift` and `getUserChoice`, and presumably a macro definition for `SIZE` (ala `#define SIZE 500`)

```
void getString(char* inputBuf, size_t maxLength); // forward declare

int main()
{
    char inputBuf[SIZE];
    int choice;

    while((choice = getUserChoice()) != 4)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                getShift();
                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                getString(inputBuf, SIZE);
                break;
            }
        }
    } 

    return 0;
}

void getString(char* inputBuf, size_t maxLength)
{
    printf("Input: \n");
    fgets(inputBuf, maxLength, stdin);
}
```